# Editing ELF binary call instruction

Tags: c, assembly, reverse-engineering, elf

I am playing around with manipulating a binary's call functions.  I have the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void myfunc2(char *str2, char *str1) {

    // enter code here
}

void myfunc(char *str2, char *str1)
{
    memcpy(str2 + strlen(str2), str1, strlen(str1));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char str1[4] = "tim";
    char str2[10] = "hello ";

    myfunc((char *)&str2, (char *)&str1);

    printf("%s\n", str2);
    
    myfunc2((char *)&str2, (char *)&str1);

    printf("%s\n", str2);

    return 0;
}

void myfunc2(char *str2, char *str1)
{
    memcpy(str2, str1, strlen(str1));
}
```

I have compiled the binary and using readelf or objdump I can see that my two functions reside at:

46: 0000000000**40072c**    52 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 myfunc2**

54: 0000000000**40064d**    77 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 myfunc**

Using the command objdump -D test (my binaries name), I can see that main has two callq functions.  I tried to edit the first one to point to myfunc2 using the above address 72c, but that does not work; causes the binary to fail.

```
000000000040069a <main>:
  40069a:   55                      push   %rbp
  40069b:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  40069e:   48 83 ec 40             sub    $0x40,%rsp
  4006a2:   89 7d cc                mov    %edi,-0x34(%rbp)
  4006a5:   48 89 75 c0             mov    %rsi,-0x40(%rbp)
  4006a9:   64 48 8b 04 25 28 00    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
  4006b0:   00 00 
  4006b2:   48 89 45 f8             mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)
  4006b6:   31 c0                   xor    %eax,%eax
  4006b8:   c7 45 d0 74 69 6d 00    movl   $0x6d6974,-0x30(%rbp)
  4006bf:   48 b8 68 65 6c 6c 6f    movabs $0x206f6c6c6568,%rax
  4006c6:   20 00 00 
  4006c9:   48 89 45 e0             mov    %rax,-0x20(%rbp)
  4006cd:   66 c7 45 e8 00 00       movw   $0x0,-0x18(%rbp)
  4006d3:   48 8d 55 d0             lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rdx
  4006d7:   48 8d 45 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  4006db:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
  4006de:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4006e1:   e8 67 ff ff ff          callq  40064d <myfunc>
  4006e6:   48 8d 45 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  4006ea:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  4006ed:   e8 0e fe ff ff          callq  400500 <puts@plt>
  4006f2:   48 8d 55 d0             lea    -0x30(%rbp),%rdx
  4006f6:   48 8d 45 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  4006fa:   48 89 d6                mov    %rdx,%rsi
  4006fd:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400700:   e8 27 00 00 00          callq  40072c <myfunc2>
  400705:   48 8d 45 e0             lea    -0x20(%rbp),%rax
  400709:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40070c:   e8 ef fd ff ff          callq  400500 <puts@plt>
  400711:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400716:   48 8b 4d f8             mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rcx
  40071a:   64 48 33 0c 25 28 00    xor    %fs:0x28,%rcx
  400721:   00 00 
  400723:   74 05                   je     40072a <main+0x90>
  400725:   e8 f6 fd ff ff          callq  400520 <__stack_chk_fail@plt>
  40072a:   c9                      leaveq 
  40072b:   c3                      retq
```

I suspect I need to do something with calculating the address information through relative location or using the lea/mov instructions.

Any assistance to learn how to modify the call function would be greatly appreciated - please no pointers on editing strings like the howtos all over most of the internet...

Comment: You should also compile your C code with e.g. `gcc -fverbose-asm -S` then look at the generated assembly code. BTW, what is your exact question? Did you read precisely the documentation of `callq` x86 machine instruction?

Comment: Instead of `myfunc((char *)&str2, (char *)&str1);`, why don't you just write `myfunc(str2, str1);`? Surely that's easier to read? I will never understand this instict to cast everywhere that so many people seem to have.

Comment: You also need to read the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation_folder/abi.pdf) spec.

Comment: **Please edit your question to improve it**. What are you exactly asking is unclear. "any help" is too broad for SO!

Comment: You can't just "rewrite" the address. You need to know the exact way `callq` instructions are encoded, and encode the new instruction in its place. If the newly encoded instruction happens to be of a different size, you're not that lucky :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to rewrite the address, you have to know the exact way the `callq` instructions are encoded.

Let's take the disassembly output of the first call:

```
4006e1: e8 67 ff ff ff          callq  40064d <myfunc>
4006e6: ...
```

You can clearly see that the instruction is encoded with 5 bytes. The `e8` byte is the instruction opcode, and `67 ff ff ff` is the address to jump to. At this point, one would ask the question, what has `67 ff ff ff` to do with `0x40064d`?

Well, the answer is that `e8` encodes a so-called "relative call" and the jump is performed relative to the location of the next instruction. You have to calculate the distance between `4006e6` and the called function in order to rewrite the address. Had the call been absolute (`ff`), you could just put the function address in these 4 bytes.

To prove that this is the case, consider the following arithmetic:

```
0x004006e6 + 0xffffff67 == 0x10040064d
```

Comment: Excellent, okay so above you stated that if the encoded instruction happens to be a different size - I may not be that lucky.  This is the same instruction so would that be okay or no?

Comment: In the particular case it shouldn't be a concern - it can be easily encoded with 5 bytes again. However, in the general case, if you need to replace an instruction with a bigger one, it would break all of the code below that instruction. The instructions below it may use PC-relative addressing or `call` addressing like this one, and all of their addresses will be offset by this difference you are introducing. If the new instruction is smaller, you can pad the end with `NOP`'s to go around this issue.

Comment: Okay so to calculate the "relative position" - is this the position from the myfunc call in main to myfunc2?  This is a bit ambiguous to me at the moment

Comment: First, find out the exact absolute addresses of `myfunc` and `myfunc2` (hint: 40064d and 40072c). Then, find the location of the instruction you want to patch. Calculate the difference between the address of the function and the address of the instruction immediately following the call. Patch the 4 bytes in this instruction with that difference (the bytes have to be in little-endian order).

Comment: Greatly appreciated and I have it working.  One last question, lets say I wanted to call a function that is in an address lower than where I am. Is the relative position a signed integer or unsigned (so it can handle reversing back up the stack)?

Comment: It is a signed integer, so you should be able to jump downwards.