# diStorm library, disassemble CALL instruction

Tags: c, x86, call, disassembly, opcode

diStorm library (http://www.ragestorm.net/distorm/) disassembles 0x86 instruction

```
e813000000
```

as

```
call 0x20
```

while it should be

```
call 0x13
```

Is it a bug or I do understand something wrong?

**Additional info**

The binary data (opcodes) transferred to diStorm's `distorm_decode` is

```
const unsigned char bin[] = { 0x55, 0x8b, 0xec, 0xE8, 0x92, 0xF8, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0xE8, 0x13, 00,00,00 };
```

Screenshot attached. [image: screenshot]

Comment: Keep in mind that the `e8` opcode together with a 4-byte quantity forms a "near, relative call, with displacement relative to next instruction". http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html should be helpful.

Comment: You can find this answer helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672064/editing-elf-binary-call-instruction/26673080#26673080

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you provided the original instruction bytes, here is a rough disassembly by hand:

```
Offset  0:  55 8b ec // not interested in these 3 bytes
Offset  3:  E8 92 F8 FF FF // a relative call instruction
Offset  8:  E8 13 00 00 00 // another relative call instruction
Offset 13:  ...
```

Adding `00 00 00 13` to the address of the next instruction (`Offset 13`) gives you the destination address, which is `0x20`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's relative to the start of opcodes.